# Local execution of sed works fine but it generates an error while executed remotely

Tags: bash, ssh, sed

The following `sed` expression executes fine when ran directly on the target server:

```
sed -i 's@\[server\]@\[server\]\
proxy-protocol-networks=192.168.1.0\/24, localhost\
max_connect_errors = 4294967295\
max_connections = 100000@' /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
```

However, when I try to execute it remotely via `ssh`:

```
$ ssh root@<IP> sed  's@\[server\]@\[server\]\
proxy-protocol-networks=192.168.1.0\/24, localhost\
max_connect_errors = 4294967295\
max_connections = 100000@' /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
```

I get the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 58: unterminated `s' command
```

Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1534401/432690

Comment: Single quote is executed locally, so that command is not longer quoted at remote server. Try a here-document.

Comment: @Wiimm: what do you mean by "here-document" ?

Comment: Here document example: `command << __EOT__ <NL> sed ... <NL> next_command ...<NL>__EOT__ <NL>`. `<NL>` is the newline character. `__EOT__` is the end-of-text marker to finish the here document.  See https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html for more details.

Comment: @Wiimm : OK, I didn't know it was called that way. Thanks for your time, butI finally gave up. I `scp`-ed the file locally, I ran `sed` and, finally I uploaded it.